# GDB stuck: [New Thread 0x2903 of process 56599]

Tags: c++, macos, gdb

I want to debug my code with gdb. My actions:

1 specify cmake flags `SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG  "-O0 -g -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic")`  and run `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug <OTHER_PARAMETERS>`

2 Run

```
sudo gdb --args ./min_wrapper ../output.json
...
Reading symbols from ./min_wrapper...
(gdb) br min_wrapper.cpp:50
Breakpoint 1 at 0x100009fad: file /Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/06_mad_optimizer/src/mad-optimizer-lib/min_wrapper.cpp, line 50.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/06_mad_optimizer/src/mad-optimizer-lib/build_release/min_wrapper ../output.json
[New Thread 0x2103 of process 58280]
```

Looks like gdb is stuck, because I don't see expected output

I am using MacOS and IntelCore I7

Comment: The obvious observation here is that your code *does not get to line 50*. I think you can ctrl-c to see where it is currently stuck. Also, you do not need `-O0` to debug. `-Og` is better in every aspect.

Comment: What happens if you interrupt the gdb (SIGINT/CTRL+C), where does it pause?